# Thread safety with Netty and Bukkit

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, netty, bukkit

I'm creating listeners for when a channel is read, and when a channel writes in Netty. Listeners are handled in the Bukkit's event system, that's not the problem, the problem is thread safety. The Bukkit Api is run on the main thread and must be in sync or basically the server will explode. Netty is run on multiple threads, so cross communication can be hard with the Bukkit api. I asked on the Bukkit forums and the best answer i got was to create an AtomicBoolean and have a while loop, this would solve the problem with syncing the cancellation of the sending and writing packets but it doesn't fix the problem of changing the packet that is being sent /written. when an event is called in Bukkit the listeners are called from each class, under @EventHandler. all of that code must be in sync with the main thread, I'm not to sure how i would use synchronized in this scenario. sorry for the bad code formatting i cant work this system very well.

```
public class ConnectionInjector extends ChannelDuplexHandler {

    private User user;
    private Channel channel;
    private PacketRecieveEvent recieve;
    private PacketSendEvent send;
    private boolean isInjected = false;
    private boolean isClosed = false;

    public ConnectionInjector(User user) {
        this.init(user.getPlayer());
    }
    public void close() {
        if (!this.isClosed) {
            this.isClosed = true;
            if (this.isInjected) {
                getChannel().eventLoop().submit(new Callable<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public Object call() throws Exception {

                        getChannel().pipeline().remove(ConnectionInjector.this);
                        return null;

                    }

                });

                this.isInjected = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isInjected() {
        return this.isInjected;
    }

    public boolean isClosed() {
        return this.isClosed;
    }


    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext context, Object packet, ChannelPromise channel) {
        if (this.isClosed()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Connection closed already");
        }
        PacketData d = new PacketData(packet);
        send = new PacketSendEvent(user, d);//the event
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(Main.getInstance(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(send); //runnable puts it on the main thread
            }
        });//end of bukkit thread back on netty
        if (!send.isCancelled()){// this possible happens before the above code which is very bad
            try {
                if (send.getPacket().getRawPacket() == null){
                    throw new IllegalStateException("sent packet was null: " + send.getPacket().getRawPacket().getClass().getName());
                }
                super.write(context, send.getPacket().getRawPacket(), channel); //possible happens before send is even created.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext context, final Object packet) throws Exception {
        PacketData p = new PacketData(packet);
        recieve = new PacketRecieveEvent(user, p);
        Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(Main.getInstance(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Bukkit.getPluginManager().callEvent(recieve); 
            }

        });
        if (recieve.isCancelled()){
            super.channelRead(context, recieve.getPacket().getRawPacket());
        }


    }

    public void injectfakePacket(Object packet) {
        if (this.isClosed()){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Injector is closed");
        }
        this.getChannel().pipeline().context("encoder").fireChannelRead(packet);
    }

    public void init(Player player) {
      this.channel = (Channel) Nms.getNetChannel(player);
        this.channel.pipeline().addBefore("packet_handler", "epickitpvp", this);
        this.isInjected = true;
    }

    public Channel getChannel() {
        if (this.channel == null){
            throw new IllegalStateException("channel is null");
        }
        return this.channel;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use synchronization if you don't have to. Your fields just need to be finalized or made volatile since the non-primitive nonfloat/nondouble fields are mainly not written to except in the constructor, an the ones that are written to are primitives, which only requires you to make volatile. By the way, it's me again :P

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Scheudler of Bukkit with ASync Threads, so you can scheudle a new Sync Task inside of the ASync Thread, because the Sync Thread will only be called when the Main-Thread is ready.

Complicated short: Scheudle a new Sync Task with

```
Bukkit.getScheudler().scheudleSyncTask(PLUGIN, new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Bukkit methods here
    }
});
```

inside of your ASync Thread and you are good.

Comment: Thats what i was doing, did you look at my code. the problem is getting and setting information between the two threads. like setCancelled(true), getPacket().setField("a", 1)

Comment: Sorry didn't see that. Then I somehow don't understand where your problem is because the syncing to Bukkit was already solved.

Comment: only calling the event was synced the rest was not, if something isnt synced the other thread could be getting the boolean before it is even instantiated. since the threads are running at different speeds and pulling / setting information at different times

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish with this code so I can't give you a direct answer, but I can clear up a few problems you're probably having with threads.

First of all, Java can and will cache variables on a per-thread basis which means you'll end up with multiple copies of the same variable with different values depending on what thread you're in. This caching can cause a lot of confusion for people who aren't aware of it. However, you can tell Java to keep a variable in a consistent state between threads by using the volatile keyword. More information about volatile can be found here: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml

If you're having trouble understanding the synchronized keyword in Java, I suggest you first do a bit of research into what a semaphore is and then revisit synchronization. A good understanding of what a semaphore is and how it works will make it easier for you to understand how to work in a multithreaded environment where the threads need to share state (however, this is a situation you should avoid when possible).

You also might find Java's concurrent collections api to be very helpful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html